# sql query many-to-many

Tags: sql, many-to-many

I have three tables:
authors (author_id, author_name), books (book_id, book_name), author_book (author_id, book_id). I want to find all authors who wrote more than two book.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for

```
select a.author_name, count(ab.book_id) total_books
from author_book ab
join authors a on a.author_id = ab.author_id
group by ab.author_name
having count(ab.book_id) > 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.autor_name
from authors a
join author_books ab on ab.author_id = a.author_id
join books b on ab.book_id = b.book_id
group by a.author_name
having count(b.book_id) > 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.author_name, count(ab.author_id) as "no_of_books"
from author_book ab
join author a on a.author_id = ab.author_id
group by a.author_name
having COUNT(a.author_name) > 2
```